Why are my Hazard Ratio coefficients so large or small in Coxph regression?
I have some grade data for an institution I work at for a specific sub population and comparing it to retention over time. In the first table below are some hazard ratios from a coxph regression in R, using D&F GPA students as the comparison group. This is a sub population commonly that leaves our institution to another one, so I am expecting to see that A's (Academic Currency) are associating with leaving vs staying.
The time unit is based on # of academic credits.

My interpretation is that a student with an A is roughly 15 times more likely to leave than student with a D or F average. As a sanity check, I thought to check what the aggregate raw data:

I am confused, because this value is quite a bit higher than the proportional ratio between the two groups. Is there a better comparison I should be making to compute a "raw" hazard ratio from the aggregate pivot table values?
Another example is below comparing the output from output for program of student (Programs 3 is  the reference group).

VS the raw data, where the proportions don't seem to support the hazard ratios here either. Program was the most predictive variable in the analysis.

For further reference, I have attached a Kaplan Maier survival plot for grades, which does not seem to indicate such large coxph coefficients.


I wonder what these data are about. You are showing that higher grades make it more likely to leave. Is this data for some kind of remedial education? If it is data for some sort of regular school, then something seems very wrong.  Could you edit your question to add this information? Also, what is the time unit?

Think of a commuter college where people leave to Big U the next town over a lot. A's get them  entrance a lot easier than D's. Time unit is academic credits.

Please also see my comment. But, assuming your data are correct:
Your interpretation is incorrect.
Cox PH is not about the likelihood of leaving, it is about the time to leaving. The hazard ratio is the instantaneous hazard. That is the risk of leaving at any given instant.
If you want to model leaving vs. not, I suggest logistic regression.
Also, I believe one reason for the large discrepancy is that not that many people leave.

I think I will move to logistic regression - on second thought I'm sure the assumption of a constant hazard ratio over time is wrong - students leave mostly after 1st or 2nd year and much fewer leave after 3rd or 4th year.

Cox does not assume a constant hazard ratio. Almost no survival analysis has that.

Sorry, I meant the typical assumption, i.e. proportional hazards. https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/assumptions-cox-regression/
